# bring the network up fails in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following this [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/tutorials.html), and trying to build the network. However, when I tried to run this command:`./ byfn.sh -m up`, but I got the following error:

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.rootcert.file: open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks very much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtlAR.png)

Comment: It seems that you haven't generated the artifacts required to bring the network up. Run '**./byfn.sh -m generate**' before running '**./ byfn.sh -m up**'.

Comment: Thanks! But in fact I have ran  './byfn.sh -m generate'  before running './ byfn.sh -m up'. And the output is as above. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you check the directory and see if 'tlsca.example.com-cert.pem' is in correct location or the location it's expecting it to be? 
Make sure you have permission to write to that directory while generating artifacts.

Comment: Oh yes, it seems there is no gopath directory in opt, and if I run 'sudo ./byfn.sh -m generate' before running './ byfn.sh -m up', there's an error saying 'Failed loading private key [321bfd7102662ad2ce78f00aafa2e59e4225dc7347f81313783a3b5a63506343]: [open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/321bfd7102662ad2ce78f00aafa2e59e4225dc7347f81313783a3b5a63506343_sk: permission denied].' after running './ byfn.sh -m up'.

Comment: So is there any solution to such a situation?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue as you are facing

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.rootcert.file: open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory
```

In my case I was entering my local path instead "**/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto**" this path. So I just copied my machine path from terminal and appended to the file path this resolved my issue.

Hope this will help in your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this point by correcting my GOPATH environment variable. 
I'm running on MacOS High Sierra (10.13.5) and following the tutorial led me to setting:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

where my $HOME environment variable was set to be

```
/Users/<username>
```

My Go installation isn't located there. I corrected my GOPATH by running the following:

```
which go
export GOPATH=<which_go_output>
```

I copied the second line into my .bash_profile and removed the following line, which the tutorial also suggests:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I too observed the same error. Finally came to know the I didn't generate the certs using `./byfn.sh generate` or
`../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml`

Please make sure above certs are generated in `crypto-config` directory in your local machine before you spinup the network.